# Pseudo :before Dynamic Background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element

Forgive me if this has been asked elsewhere. I don't know enough about what I don't know to yield effective search results.

The idea is that, based on user input, a div is assigned the `.flipped` class and it's background-image is rotated 180 deg. The div itself cannot be rotated. Is it possible to have the background-image in the pseudo element dynamically set based on the actual elements current background-image?

I have the actual image rotation set just fine:

```
.flipped:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url('../../images/cards/back.png');
    background-size: contain;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Works great if I manually set the background-image as shown above but this does not work for my application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the pseudo background image shoud inherit its parent background ?

Comment: Just set it to inherit `background: inherit;`

Comment: Note o use `background:`, not `background-image:`

Comment: Interesting, background-image worked but I'll take your word for it. Also, thank you, that's exactly what I need. I think I was looking for too difficult a solution. Thank you!